# Get the time difference in days between two rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, apply

I wrote a code that works, but I am pretty sure that I can use some pandas function to make it better. I'd appreciate if you can give me some advices.

For a bit of context, I have crawled some social media posts and I wanted to get the time difference in days between two posts (and I did it for different search keywords).

DF looks like this:
- keyword   --- date
0   서예지 2021-07-25
1   서예지 2021-07-25
2   서예지 2021-07-25
3   서예지 2021-07-25
4   서예지 2021-07-22
... ... ...
8808    박초롱 2018-02-05
8809    박초롱 2018-02-03
8810    박초롱 2018-01-28
8811    박초롱 2018-01-15
8812    박초롱 2018-01-03

I wrote this code which gives me the result that I want: a column with the timedifference in days between the post one the row and the one before.

(column 8 is the date column)

```
df_score = df_score.sort_values(by='date', ascending=True)
df_score['time_diff'] = pd.Series('', dtype='timedelta64[ns]')

temp2 = pd.DataFrame()
for keyword in df_score['keyword'].unique(): 
  temp = df_score.loc[df_score['keyword']==f'{keyword}']
  temp.iat[0,-1] = temp.iat[0,8] - temp.iat[0,8] # set first value of the table to 0
  for i in range(1, len(temp['score'])):
    temp.iat[i,-1] = temp.iat[i,8] - temp.iat[i-1,8]
  
  temp2 = temp2.append(temp)

df_score['time_diff'] = temp2['time_diff']
```

How can I improve it? I don't think that it is ideal to have a loop when pandas function exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df_score['time_diff'] = df_score.groupby('keyword')['date'].diff()
```

Comment: That was exactly the answer I was looking for, thanks!